# Changing Agent color based on queue waiting time

Tags: anylogic

I am creating a DES model with an animation. I would like to show a change in color for agents that have been waiting in a queue for more than a certain time. One option I thought of is to use a timeout and change the color on exit of the timeout, but the problem with this approach is it may mess up the order of the agents in the queue.

Is there a way in AnyLogic to be able to model this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a normal event manually triggered... you can set that up in the event properties (mode: user control), so when an agent enters the queue you start the event doing agent.event.restart(timeout,TIMEUNITS);

and in the event you change the color of the agent

obviously this event has to be inside the agent