# Object should change color after 2 second, when agent enterers in "delay" Block

Tags: simulation, anylogic

When agent enters in block the Object (rectangle) changes color instantly. What I want is when agent enters in block object (rectangle) it should take 1 or 2 seconds to change its color.

**My Approach**

- Make a boolean variable called "temperature".
- on "On enter" of Delay block  `temperature = true`
- on "On exit" of Delay block  `temperature = false`
- In object (rectangle) "Fill Color" is `temperature == true ? red: brown`

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64748836/changing-agent-color-based-on-queue-waiting-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Dynamic Event, name it `myDE`. Give it 1 argument `myAgent` of type YourAgentType. In the action code, you write `myAgent.myRectangle.setFillColor(yourColor);`

In the "on enter" code of the delay block, you create the event using `create_myDE(2, SECOND, agent)`

Now every agent arriving in the delay will schedule an event 2 sec after entering that will change that agent's rectangle.

Comment: But rectangle in on the main. So 'myAgent.myRectangle.setFillColor(yourColor);' will not work.

Comment: Well, then adjust the code to get to Main instead. `main.myRectangle...`.